# Is it possible to get property from InvocationExpression?

Tags: c#, linq

I have following code:

```
      var existing = new[] { "first", "second" };
      Func<TestType, string> func = type => type.TextCol;

      Expression<Func<TestType, bool>> exp = q => existing.Contains(func(q));
```

and have Expression visitor.
Visitor sees `MethodCallExpression` which is `Contains` in original expression and it has two parameters - one is array of string values, second is `InvocationExpression`, which is `func(q)` part in original expression.

I need to extract property name from this `InvocationExpression` used in original function somehow. I think that should be possible, but looking at the `InvocationExpression` instance in debugger can't get any idea how, may be someone could help?

## Update

What I intend to do is

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> FindExisting<TEntity, TValue>(IEnumerable<TEntity> list, Func<TEntity, TValue> property)
{
     var values = list.Select(property);
     Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> exp = q => list.Contains(property(q)); 
     return db.Select<TEntity>(exp);
}
```

## Update 2

Whole story :)
So ServiceStack.OrmLite has method [SaveAll](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/OrmLiteWriteExtensions.cs), which takes list of entities, checks in database which of them exist and updates them, rest is inserted. All of that is working fine, problem is, that they are using Id field to check if item exists in database. In my case I have another unique field, which is primary key in external system, and as I get entities from external system, for me to check if I need to insert or update them would be much easier using that field, not Id, so I thought I would write extension method, which does the same as SaveAll, just has possibility to pass property which is used to determine if item needs update or insert.

Comment: As far as I can see - you can't do this.  `Func<TestType, string>` is a compiled expression, which doesn't contain Expression Nodes with metadata, but point to a method with `IL`

Comment: Hm, in such case could I rewrite code somehow to have ability to pass property using expression at runtime and be able to get that property name in my expression visitor?

Comment: you gave some code in `update` section. Could you give high-level description of you intent? What are you trying to achieve beyond passing property as parameter with `FindExisting` method

Comment: updated question with whole story